# TFS 2012-based reports and settings open in separate browser window instead of tab in VS 2012 IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

In the process of switching my folks over to TFS 2012, I was evaluating the team project reports I moved over.  When I double-clicked on a report to open it, instead of seeing it in a tab within my VS 2012 IDE, it opens in a separate web browser window.

This behavior exhibits in migrated team projects (from 2010 to 2012), as well as newly created team projects.  I'm inclined to think it's a configuration issue missed on my part, but I can't seem to nail it down.

[Migration details: upgrade performed by detaching 2010 collection, reattaching to running instance of TFS2012 on new hardware. ReportServer database was moved separately. Hardware is all WinSrv2008R2, SQL2012 Standard.]

**UPDATE:** altered title as this is happening to any/all settings and controls, as well, for any given team project (Security, Group Membership, Work Item Areas, etc). Anything that is URL-based. So, at least it's misbehaving consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this is the expected behavior for TFS 2012. All of the controls you mentioned are part of Web Access and should be viewed/altered in a browser and not VS.

Comment: You understood correctly. It appears I was under the impression that all of these reports, controls, etc, though web based, were suppose to appear within a tab in the IDE (i.e. v10 style). Thank you!